# Quotients of null sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Let $-1<\alpha_n<0<\beta_n<1$ and $\alpha_n, \beta_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

It's clear that $0<\frac{\beta_n}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}<1$. Is it true that sequence $\frac{\beta_n}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}$ converges?

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider this example: $\alpha_n$ is any sequence converging to $0$ with $-1/4<\alpha_n<0$ and
$$
\beta_n=\begin{cases}-2\,\alpha_n & \text{if $n$ is even,}\\-4\,\alpha_n & \text{if $n$ is odd.}\end{cases}
$$
Then $\beta_n\to0$ and
$$
\frac{\beta_n}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}=\begin{cases}2/3 & \text{if $n$ is even,}\\4/5 & \text{if $n$ is odd.}\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

No.

Take $\alpha_n = -\frac12$ and $\beta_n = \frac1n$. Then,
$$\frac{\beta_n}{\beta_n - \alpha_n} \to 0.$$

Take $\alpha_n = -\frac1n$ and $\beta_n = \frac12$. Then,
$$\frac{\beta_n}{\beta_n - \alpha_n} \to 1.$$

If you interlace both sequences, the quotient does not converge.